# Set transparency dynamically in Konsole

Tags: vim, transparency, kde-plasma, konsole

I like the transparency effect on Konsole, but when I'm in vim I need to focus and it can be distracting.  Is there a way to dynamically turn the transparency on and off, depending on whether my current window is in vim?
Maybe I could run a script in place of vim that looks like this:
set konsole transparency off;
vim;
set konsole transparency on;
Any ideas?

Comment: IMO this is a perfect question for SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch a new konsole with

```
konsole --notransparency -e vim
```

for changing current konsole properties you need to deal with dbus. [Scripting Konsole](http://docs.kde.org/development/en/kdebase-apps/konsole/scripting.html)